# How to solve: Error: Route.get() requires a callback function but got a [object Object]?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes, express-router

### Routes Folder Structure

Note: There was no problem, until I added `docs_router.js`
[image: routes folder structure]

**docs_router.js**

```js
const { control_docs_v1, ipManager } = require('../controllers/indexer')
const router = require('express').Router()
router.get('/v1', ipManager, control_docs_v1)
module.exports = router
```

**location.js**

```js
const { ipManager, sendData } = require('../controllers/indexer')
const router = require('express').Router()
router.get('/weather/:loc', ipManager, sendData)
module.exports = router
```

**indexer.js**

```js
const location = require('./location')
const docs_router = require("./docs_router")

module.exports = {
    location,
    docs_router
}
```

In the entry file, `index.js` I have,

```js
app.use("path1", location)
app.use("path", docs_router)
```

Is there any issue with **exporting multiple router object?**
How to use `router` in righth way?

### What I want to achieve

- I want to keep the routes for specific features in separate files.
- I want only one file to export everything from the routes folder

Comment: should avoid circular dependencies

Comment: what is circular dependencies

Comment: js scripts shouldn't import each other -- might want to rethink your project structure

Comment: @skara9 are u suggesting, not to use `indexer.js`??

Comment: @skara9 edited the question. please check

Comment: so you have two separate files both named `indexer.js`?

Comment: no. in routes folder, I have only one. Another is in the controllers folder

Comment: The second parameter to Router get() must be callback function. But it looks like you are passing an object. So verify the type of ipManager

Comment: @SankethB.K `ipManager` is an async-await-function. It has been used in location.js from long before. This issue started when I added docs_router.js today.

Answer (score 1):

Finally solved.
I made these changes.

**docs_router.js**

```js
const { control_docs_v1, ipManager } = require('../controllers/indexer')
const router = require('express').Router()
router.get('/v1', ipManager.ipManager, control_docs_v1.control_docs_v1)
module.exports = router
```

**location.js**

```js
const { ipManager, sendData } = require('../controllers/indexer')
const router = require('express').Router()
router.get('/weather/:loc', ipManager.ipManager, sendData)
module.exports = router
```

Doing this resolved the error.

Comment: If anyone can explain, why this is happening, please edit the answer to add your points.